# Function Returning Pointer to Struct Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I am working on a project that deals with a struct and has various functions that manipulate the given struct.

I have started off with my initial function that just allocates the memory for the struct, and initialises each item in the struct and then returns a pointer to the struct. I have already defined the struct in my header file. I then have a main file that I will eventually use to run all my functions, however I am having trouble just running this first one, it seg faults every time I run it.

header:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct Double_Array{
    double** array;
    int rowsize;
    int colsize;
};

struct Double_Array* double_array(int,int);
```

function:

```
#include "header.h"


struct Double_Array* double_array( int row, int col){

    int i;

    struct Double_Array* ptrDouble_Array;

    ptrDouble_Array = (struct Double_Array*) malloc(sizeof(struct Double_Array));

    ptrDouble_Array -> rowsize = row;

    ptrDouble_Array -> colsize = col;
    for(i=0;i< ptrDouble_Array -> colsize ; i++){
        ptrDouble_Array -> array[i] = malloc((sizeof(double))*(row));
    }
    return(ptrDouble_Array);
}
```

mainline:

```
#include "header.h"


int main(){
    srand(time(0));
    printf("running");
    int i;
    int j;
    struct Double_Array* ptr;

    ptr = double_array( 5, 5);

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        free(ptr->array[i]);
    }
    free(ptr);

    return(0);

}
```

I've spent a while looking for possible issues, but everything looks logically correct to me.

What is causing the Seg fault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're allocating space for each `array[i]`, but you never allocate space for `array`.  So `ptrDouble_Array->array[i]` is dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, which causes the segfault.

Add the allocation:

```
ptrDouble_Array->array = malloc((sizeof(double *))*(col));
for(i=0;i< ptrDouble_Array->colsize ; i++){
    ptrDouble_Array->array[i] = malloc((sizeof(double))*(row));
}
```

And don't forget to `free` it:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    free(ptr->array[i]);
}
free(ptr->array);
free(ptr);
```